# Scheduled Data Export: how to obtain ContentVersion linking data

Tags: data-export, contentversion, contentdocumentlink

I've used the Data Export feature to pull down `ContentVersion` data for Files and (Enhanced) Notes from a Salesforce org that's being migrated into a different org. I've been unable to locate the `ContentDocument` and `ContentDocumentLink` data connecting these records to their parents.

Is this data included or is it possible to include it in the data export ZIP file? If not, can I rely on a SOQL query run as a System Administrator to get back all of the linking data, even for private files?

Comment: `ContentDocument` is created automatically when you insert the `ContentVersion` into the target org; Hence, you will need to do the migration in steps - first ContentVersion + other Sobjects, then insert ContentDocumentLinks that you build manually in Excel using the IDs of the parents to ContentDocumentLink in the target org

Comment: Thanks, @cropredy - I had forgotten about automatic creation of `ContentDocument`. `ContentDocumentLink` has weird query restrictions (requires a `LinkedEntityId` or `ContentDocumentId` filter). Any ideas on the best way to extract the entire table for migration and matching?

Comment: I could imagine scripting a loop over the Ids of all the `ContentDocuments` in the instance and batching them for `IN` query filters, but that just sounds tedious.

Comment: hmm -- a batch class that queried all ContentDocuments (`start()`) whose `execute()` did query on `ContentDocumentLink` and wrote results to some custom migration object?

Comment: I like that idea. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to realize is that `ContentDocument` can't be directly inserted; it is inserted automatically when the first ContentVersion is inserted. *ContentDocument acts as a parent for each version of the file - i.e., each child `ContentVersion`*

So an approach would be:

- Export all ContentVersion from the source (including the ID)
- Insert the ContentVersion to the target org. Associate in some place (Excel), the target ContentVersion.Id to the source org's ContentVersion.Id
- Export and insert all Sobjects (like Account, Opportunity, etc - i.e., those Sobjects that are the parents of ContentDocumentLink as `LinkedEntityId`. Be sure to keep track of the new (target) sobject Ids and associate them (Excel) back to the source Sobject Ids.
- Export the ContentDocumentLink from the source org. This is tricky because you can't SOQL all of the ContentDocumentLink without a Where clause.  If you don't have too many ContentDocument, you can do this in one SOQL but if you have way too many (exceed size of SOQL string), you will need to write a small batchable class to export the ContentDocumentLinks to a custom object that you can in turn export using DataLoader.
- Manipulate the exported ContentDocumentLink from the source org (Excel) to replace the source LinkedEntityId with the ID of that Sobject in the target; do the same for the ContentDocumentId.
- Use DataLoader to insert the ContentDocumentLink into the target

Details on the batchable:

`start()` - query all ContentDocument

`execute()` - query all `ContentDocumentLink` for the execute's scope argument (i.e. a list of `ContentDocument`. Write results to a custom migration object - `ContentDocumentLink_Migration__c` that has two fields: `SourceLinkedEntityId__c` and `SourceContentDocumentLink__c`